# Change the name of the ID in Exposed ORM

Tags: kotlin, orm, kotlin-exposed

i have defined a table and a row in Kotlin:

```
    object Countries : UUIDTable("country") {
        val uuid: Column<UUID> = uuid("uuid").autoGenerate()
        val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
        val code: Column<String> = varchar("code", 2)
        override val primaryKey = PrimaryKey(uuid, name = "country_pk")
    }

    class Country(uuid: EntityID<UUID>) : UUIDEntity(uuid) {
        companion object : UUIDEntityClass<Country>(Countries)
        var uuid by Countries.uuid
        var name by Countries.name
        var code by Countries.code
    }
```

As you can see i use a UUID with the column name "uuid" as my primary key.

When i do a select:

```
var country = Country.find { Countries.code eq "GB" }.first()
```

the query fails with the following error:

```
org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column country.id does not exist
```

The reason is simple. The generated SQL query looks like:

```
SELECT country.id, country.uuid, country."name", country.code FROM country WHERE country.code = ?
```

So my question now is: Where is the ID Column coming from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id column is declared in `UUIDTable` class :

```
open class UUIDTable(name: String = "", columnName: String = "id") : IdTable<UUID>(name) {
    override val id: Column<EntityID<UUID>> = uuid(columnName)
            .autoGenerate()
            .entityId()
    override val primaryKey by lazy { super.primaryKey ?: PrimaryKey(id) }
}
```

If you use `uuid` column as a primary key then you could just remove it from declaration and provide `uuid` as a name for an id column like:

```
object Countries : UUIDTable("country", "uuid") {
    val name: Column<String> = varchar("name", 255)
    val code: Column<String> = varchar("code", 2)
}
```